# CNN results are different in keras and tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

i am recently studying machine learning. so I make some cnn model in keras and tensorflow(not using keras) to practice skills. But the cnn result from keras and tensorflow is not same. it is very confusing.

the keras result is 68% and tensorflow is 66.6%

here is tensorflow code:

```
def convolution(self, inputs_fw):

    inputs_fw = tf.nn.dropout(inputs_fw, keep_prob=self.dropout_keep_prob)

    with tf.name_scope('forward_conv'):
        fil1 = 2
        fil2 = 3

        conv1_fw = tf.layers.conv1d(inputs_fw,filters=100,kernel_size=fil1,padding="VALID",activation=tf.nn.tanh)#tanh
        print "print conv1"
        print conv1_fw
        conv1_fw = conv1_fw + self.cbiases['convolution1']
        pool_fw = tf.layers.max_pooling1d(inputs=conv1_fw,pool_size=self.max_sentence_len-fil1+1,strides=self.max_sentence_len-fil1+1)
        print pool_fw

        pool_fw_flat =tf.reshape(pool_fw, [-1,1*100])

        conv1_fw2 = tf.layers.conv1d(inputs_fw,filters=100,kernel_size=fil2,padding="VALID",activation=tf.nn.tanh)#tanh
        print "print conv12"
        conv1_fw2 = conv1_fw2 + self.cbiases['convolution2']
        print conv1_fw2
        pool_fw2 = tf.layers.max_pooling1d(inputs=conv1_fw2,pool_size=self.max_sentence_len-fil2+1,strides=self.max_sentence_len-fil2+1)
        print pool_fw2

        pool_fw_flat2 =tf.reshape(pool_fw2, [-1,1*100])


    output = tf.concat([pool_fw_flat,pool_fw_flat2],1)

    predict = tf.matmul(output, self.weights['softmax_conv']) + self.biases['softmax_conv']

    print predict.get_shape()
    return predict
```

the loss and accuracy is made by:

```
    with tf.name_scope('loss'):
        cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=prob, labels=self.y))

    with tf.name_scope('train'):
        global_step = tf.Variable(0, name="tr_global_step", trainable=False)
        optimizer = tf.train.AdadeltaOptimizer(learning_rate=self.learning_rate).minimize(cost, global_step=global_step)

    with tf.name_scope('predict'):
        correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prob, 1), tf.argmax(self.y, 1))
        # accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))
        accuracy = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.int32))
```

Did i make some mistake?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason could be the dropout layer in your code, it will sample the layer output randomly, try to re-run your tensorflow code twice, you will also get different results.

```
inputs_fw = tf.nn.dropout(inputs_fw, keep_prob=self.dropout_keep_prob)
```

Comment: re-run, the result is nearly same(the data set is big, so it works). But I agree dropout layer may evoke some problem to layer output randomly. so i will check that. Thanks!

Comment: i think dropout layer is not problem

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are nopt using `softmax` to get probabilities

```
logits = tf.matmul(output, self.weights['softmax_conv']) + self.biases['softmax_conv']
predict = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(output, self.weights['softmax_conv']) + self.biases['softmax_conv'])
# is training True/False
inputs_fw = tf.nn.dropout(inputs_fw, keep_prob=self.dropout_keep_prob, is_training=is_training)
```

Comment: mean that i am not use the softmax? . I use softmax in 'loss' name scope

Comment: sry i am not write this code : prob = self.convolution(inputs). but anyway i am use the softmax